# VBS RegEx Search and Replace

Tags: regex, replace, vbscript, numbers

I am attempting to use a vbs script to replace the limit value in a .ini file that contains the following line:
CC_refund_limit=####.##
Unfortunately the ####.## can be any dollar value. I am replacing with a standard:
CC_refund_limit=500.00

I have attempted the following with every variation of \d \d+ enclosed in every bracket known to mankind and have even attempted [0-999] on a test file. The only way I can get this to work has been with the following code and only if the string contains an actual dollar value as written. I have over 1600 instances on as many different servers to replace this on.

Any guidance would be appreciated:

```
`Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\EDC\Edc.ini", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, "CC_refund_limit=200.00", "CC_refund_limit=500.00")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\EDC\Edc.ini", ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

`

Comment: Is it a single line containing just that text ? If you don't care what the dollar amount is `(?i)CC_refund_limit=[$\d.]*`

Comment: Re URL: Search and replace REPALCE with REPLACE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Const ForReading = 1 
 Const ForWriting = 2 
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\EDC\Edc.ini", ForReading) 
 strText = objFile.ReadAll
 objFile.Close
Set r = New Regexp
With r
  .pattern = "CC_refund_limit=\d+\.\d+"
  .global = true
End with
StrNewText = r.Replace(strText,"CC_refund_limit=500.00")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\EDC\Edc.ini", ForWriting) 
objFile.WriteLine strNewText 
objFile.Close
```

Comment: Genuine question: What's the point of writing two extra lines for `With` and `End With` when you could have just stuck the `r` in front of `.pattern` and `.global`?

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I was working on a version of this as well, but just couldn't get it to do anything. I appreciate the help!!!